# What does "LDS" stand for in the openstack reference implementation?

Tags: juju, maas, cloud, openstack, landscape

Looking on this page, I see "LDS" mentioned.

http://www.ubuntu.com/cloud/ubuntu-openstack/reference-architecture Go to the "Services Virtualized High Availability" tab, and look at the virtualized machines under hypervisors 2 & 3.

What is it?

Comment: Doing a Ctrl+F on the page did not yield any results(case sensitive). Where is it?

Comment: @Jobin Sorry, it's part of an image, so that's why your browser doesn't find it. I forgot to specify what "tab" of the page I was looking on, I've updated my question to answer your question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

LDS stands for "Landscape Dedicated Server". From [landscape.ubuntu.com](http://landscape.ubuntu.com):

> The Landscape systems management tool helps you monitor, manage and update your entire Ubuntu infrastructure from a single interface. Part of Canonical’s Ubuntu Advantage support service, Landscape brings you intuitive systems management tools combined with world-class support.

See also:

- [LDS release notes](https://help.landscape.canonical.com/LDS/ReleaseNotes11.07.20120217-2)
- [Ubuntu Enterprise Summit on LDS](http://www.ubuntu.com/sites/www.ubuntu.com/files/active/Landscape%20Dedicated%20Server.pdf)

Comment: Aha, I saw the L and thought it might have something to do with that, but I couldn't guess what the rest of it was for. (And obviously, google wouldn't be of help because of the much more common use of the abbreviation.)

Answer (score 5):

Landscape Dedicated Server (LDS)

> Landscape is the systems management tool for Ubuntu OpenStack included
>   with Ubuntu Advantage. It allows you to manage, audit and report on
>   your Ubuntu OpenStack cloud and services running within its easily as
>   one, making your entire environment more cost-effective.<sup>[Cloud
>   management](http://www.ubuntu.com/cloud/management)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Further to the above answers you should note that there are two ways to use Landscape - as a hosted service at landscape.canonical.com or as a "Landscape Dedicated Server" on your own network.